# Parsedown set image width and height

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsedown

Currently I use CodeIgniter 3.1.3 and [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) / [Markdown Guide](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

With parse down I would like to be able to set the width and height of the image

```
![enter image description][1]

[1]: http://www.example.com/image.png '100x200' <-- widthxheight
```

**I try the the way above but sets image title instead.**

Output would be

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png" width="100" height="200" alt="enter image description">
```

> **Question** in parsedown library is there any way to modify it so can get
>   and set the width and height of image?

```
protected function inlineImage($Excerpt)
{
    if ( ! isset($Excerpt['text'][1]) or $Excerpt['text'][1] !== '[')
    {
        return;
    }

    $Excerpt['text']= substr($Excerpt['text'], 1);

    $Link = $this->inlineLink($Excerpt);

    if ($Link === null)
    {
        return;
    }

    $Inline = array(
        'extent' => $Link['extent'] + 1,
        'element' => array(
            'name' => 'img',
            'attributes' => array(
                'src' => $Link['element']['attributes']['href'],
                'alt' => $Link['element']['text'],
                'width' => '',
                'height' => ''
            ),
        ),
    );

    $Inline['element']['attributes'] += $Link['element']['attributes'];

    unset($Inline['element']['attributes']['href']);

    return $Inline;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last element from this (reference) syntax `[1]: http://www.example.com/image.png '100x200'`

Will be passed as `title` attribute, so you might do it this way:

```
class MyParsedown extends Parsedown
{
    protected function inlineImage($Excerpt)
    {
        $Inline = parent::inlineImage($Excerpt);

        if (!isset($Inline['element']['attributes']['title'])) { return $Inline; }

        $size = $Inline['element']['attributes']['title'];

        if (preg_match('/^\d+x\d+$/', $size)) {
            list($width, $height) = explode('x', $size);

            $Inline['element']['attributes']['width'] = $width;
            $Inline['element']['attributes']['height'] = $height;

            unset ($Inline['element']['attributes']['title']);
        }

        return $Inline;
    }
}
```

Attribute will be changed to `width`+`height` if `title` matches `NUMERICxNUMERIC` pattern. You might limit number of digits or size to protect breaking the page, also leading 0 should be excluded (or sizes with only `0`).

Comment: I tried to extend it codeigniter way but no luck is there another way to mix it in with my code

Comment: @wolfgang1983 It shouldn't be a problem. How do you load `Parsedown` library? If you're using `$autoload` array then both `Parsedown` and `MyParsedown` (or whatever you name this class & file) should be registered. The only easier way would be altering original file by pasting body of this method (without initial parent call) at the end of original one (line 1188)

Comment: If I put the parse down library in the system libraries and not application then use MY_Parsedown in application libraries then it works.

Comment: @shudder _"pasting body of this method (without initial parent call) at the end of original one (line 1188)"_ Not sure if I've done it correct. Just copy and paste your method at the end of the current `Parsedown.php` file ([Parsedown with Image Resize](https://pastebin.com/YFkYtcDk)). Unfortunately, it did not worked. Any idea why?

Comment: @shudder Just found the issue: `$parsedown = new MyParsedown;`

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight variation from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41609464/5713208) to make it possible to **keep the original aspect ratio** by setting width or height to zero:

```
class MyParsedown extends Parsedown
{
    protected function inlineImage($Excerpt)
    {
        $Inline = parent::inlineImage($Excerpt);

        if (!isset($Inline['element']['attributes']['title'])) { return $Inline; }

        $size = $Inline['element']['attributes']['title'];

        if (preg_match('/^\d+x\d+$/', $size)) {
            list($width, $height) = explode('x', $size);

            if($width > 0) $Inline['element']['attributes']['width'] = $width;
            if($height > 0) $Inline['element']['attributes']['height'] = $height;

            unset ($Inline['element']['attributes']['title']);
        }

        return $Inline;
    }
}
```